# Which application can mount or open the network shared directory?

Tags: networking, nautilus, lan

I am new to Ubuntu and I don't know how to open the Network and which application can open the network locations ?

Actually I tried with the following steps on first time I was connected but after that my friend changed the default file opener and I don't know what is the default application which can open the network locations...

1) nautilus

2) network

3) my local networks pc.

4) LOGIN

There you go...but now what to do now Ubuntu opens the location with the Ubuntu Software Center....

Comment: Nice friends you have :), what did he change? Normally you can browse network shares with nautilus. ("Network" on the left pane in a nautilus window). I think you should ask your friend what he did exactly.

Comment: Actually he did the opener application to the Software center instead of the default network place opener application.

Comment: That is odd, with what purpose? Could you let him write down here what he did. It seems totally unclear.

Comment: Got it now.... :)

Answer (score 1):

Ohk actually I got it...

Step 1) Open nautilus

Step 2) Right click on Network location apeared on left panel.

Step 3) Click Open

Step 4) Select the network node.

Step 5) Open with another application.

Step 6) Show  Other applications.

Step 7) Choose Files application

Step 8) Select

There you go....